# Android ActionBar SearchView Autocomplete for JSON listview

Tags: android, json, autocomplete, android-actionbar, searchview

So,i am trying to make a searchview on my actionBar so when i type,autocompltes or shows the Json listview in a list format in that searchview ,and so that i can click on those i just searched. But i find it hard to implement.Everything else is working fine.I can display the list of json parsed elemnts and geet serializable content.Now i just need the searchbar to function

Here is my java class for the ListAdapter and JSON parsing.

```
public class Collegelist extends ActionBarActivity {

HTTPConnection http;



List<Colleges> college = new ArrayList<Colleges>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.college_list);
    http = new HTTPConnection(getApplicationContext());

    if (http.isNetworkConnection()) {

        //String data = http.HTTPGetData("http://localhost/minorproject/show.php");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),data ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        task.execute();
}
    else {


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "check your connection",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}


AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String data = http.HTTPGetData("http://my-ip-address/minorproject/show.php");
        return data;


    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        populateList(result);
        displayList();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

};
protected void populateList(String result) {
    try {
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result);
        String res = jobj.getString("success");
        if (!res.equals("true")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JSON Error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            JSONArray data = jobj.getJSONArray("msg");
        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"successss",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject col = data.getJSONObject(i);
                Colleges cg = new Colleges(col.getString("cname"),
                        col.getString("caddress"),
                        col.getString("ccontact_a"),
                        col.getString("ccontact_b"),
                        col.getString("cwebsites"));

                college.add(cg);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


}


protected void displayList() {
    ArrayAdapter<Colleges> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Colleges>(this, R.layout.list_item,college){

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
            //set values
            Colleges c = college.get(position);
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(c.getName());
        /*((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address)).setText(c.getAddress());*/



            return view;
        }

    };

    final ListView collegelistnew = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    collegelistnew.setAdapter(adapter);

    collegelistnew.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
            /*Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "You clicked position" + position + "with item name"
                            + college.get(position).getName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/


            Intent newIntent =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CollegeDetails.class);

            newIntent.putExtra("college", college.get(position));
            startActivity(newIntent);



        }

    });

}
```

> and my getter and setter class

```
public class Colleges implements Serializable{
String cname,caddress,ccontact,cwebsites,ccontactb;

public Colleges( String cname, String cwebsites,String caddress, String ccontact, String ccontactb) {
    this.cname = cname;
    this.caddress = caddress;
    this.ccontact = ccontact;
    this.ccontact = ccontactb;
    this.cwebsites =  cwebsites;

}

public String getName() {
    return cname;
}

public void setName(String cname) {

    this.cname = cname;
}

public String getAddress() {

    return caddress;
}

public void setAddress(String caddress) {

    this.caddress = caddress;
}

public String getContact() {
    return ccontact;
}

public void setContact(String ccontact) {
    this.ccontact = ccontact;
}

public String getContactb() {
    return ccontactb;
}

public void setContactb(String ccontactb) {
    this.ccontactb = ccontactb;
}

public String getWebsites(){
    return cwebsites;
}

  public void setWebsites(String cwebsites){
      this.cwebsites = cwebsites;
  }
```

**Here is menu_main xml file**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your list is ready and adapter is also ready to be shown.

From `SearchView` what you can get is the current text that the user has typed or typing. What you have to do now is pass this text into a method that would create new filtered list.

On `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) SearchActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView;

        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

            if (searchView != null) {
                
                searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                        setSearchAdapter(s);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                        setSearchAdapter(s);
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            }
        }
```

You will do your listing tasks in method setSearchAdapter(s), on the basis of the String 's' you will have to recreate a list on every text change that will be populated using the adapter.

This is how your method should look like

```
private void setSearchAdapter(String s) {
       // filter list codes
       // ....
        searchAdapter =new SearchAdapter(SearchActivity.this,
                filteredList);
        listView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
    }
```

There are many ways to create a filtered list.

1. If you want to save your data in database then you can create Virtual Table and query for search as follows

   Cursor cursor = myDataProvider.query(VirtualTable.CONTENT_URI, null, VirtualTable.NAME + " MATCH ? ", new String[]{s + "*"}, null, null);

Note: For simplicity, you can use raw Match query.

Then populate it using suitable adapter class.

2. We can use [Filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) class for asynchronous filter as follows:

   private class MyFilter extends Filter {

   ```
   @Override
   protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
       FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
       for (int i = 0; i < collegeList.size(); i++) {
           String name = collegeList.get(i);
           if (name.toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
               nFilteredList.add(name);
           }
       }
       results.values = nFilteredList;
       results.count = nFilteredList.size();
       return results;
   }

   @Override
   protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
       filteredList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
   }
   ```

   }

You need to call `searchAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);` on text change and override `getFilter()` method in your adapter.

I hope this solves your query.